# Confused about bind() in javascript

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I pulled the code below from this tutorial: [tutorial](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/23/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/)

If you can bind this from a parent function to an anonymous inner function, then what do you do if you want to reference "this" in the anonymous  inner function at some later time? Does "this" not exist for the anonymous inner function?

```
render: function () 
{

    this.getAsyncData(function () {

        this.specialFunction();

        this.anotherSpecialFunction();

    }.bind(this));

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what do you do if you want to reference "this" in the anonymous inner function at some later time?

There is no way to refer to the value of `this` that the callback would have if we hadn't called `.bind`.

However, you don't have to use `.bind`, there are other ways to use the `this` value of the "parent" function: [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

> Does "this" not exist for the anonymous inner function?

`this` is an implicit value in *every* function. Which value it has is determined by how the function is *called*, unless the function is explicitly bound to a certain value (via `.bind`).

For example, if you call a function "normally", such as `func()`, then `this` will refer to the global object (`window` in browsers). The API documentation usually explains which value `this` has inside a callback. If it doesn't mention anything explicitly, then you can assume that `this` refers to the global object, which is not very useful in most cases, and thus it is no problem to "override" it via `.bind`.
But even if `this` is set to a specific value in the callback, that value is often also passed as argument to the callback. Being able to access the value via `this` is just for convenience. But again, it depends on how the API is designed and is usually explained in the API documentation.

---

For more information about `this`, have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 1):

The `this` context is set every time a function is called. If there is no context (as is the case with most callbacks), then `this` is lost.

It is more common to see:

```
var self = this;
// code using self instead of this here
```

The above is more browser-compatible due to `.bind` being relatively new.

Comment: *"If there is no context (as is the case with most callbacks), then this is lost."* This statement is a bit confusing. `this` always exists.

Comment: Is this just undefined in a callback unless there is a call to bind?

Comment: @user1202394—in non–strict mode, *this* always references an object. If it's not set in the call or by *bind*, it defaults to the global object (window in a browser). In strict mode, it's left exactly as set by the call so can be set to any value. So if not set, it's left with the *undefined* value.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an anonymous callback, `this` usually refers to the `window` object. A good example is with `setTimeout`:

```
var someObject = {
    set: function() { /* ... */ },
    doSomething: function() {
        // right here, "this" is "someObject"
        setTimeout(function() {
            // whereas right here, "this" is "window"
        });
    }
}
```

A lot of people solve this conflict like this:

```
var someObject = {
    set: function() { /* ... */ },
    doSomething: function() {
        var that = this;

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(that) // => now it refers to "doSomething"
        });
    }
}
```

That's where `bind` comes into play.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E3umR/):

```
var someObject = {
    set: function() { /* ... */ },
    doSomething: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(this) // => now it refers to "doSomething"
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

### Edit

Felix Kling made a good comment on this answer. For this answer, I'm assuming you're calling `someObject.doSomething()`, and not calling the `doSomething()` method a different context.

Comment: `// right here, "this" is "someObject"`, only if the function is called as `someObj.doSomething()`.

Comment: @FelixKling, yeah good point. Edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

*If you can bind this from a parent function to an anonymous inner function, then what do you do if you want to reference "this" in the anonymous inner function at some later time?*

You won't be able to, if you want to reference the outer `this` then set `this` to a variable and don't use bind.

```
var that = this;
```

*Does "this" not exist for the anonymous inner function?*

`this` always exists.

Simple example:

```
this.name = 'Bob';

function sayHello() {
  return ['Hello,', this.name].join(' ');
}

console.log(sayHello()); // "Hello, Bob"
console.log(sayHello.bind({name: 'Ana'})()); // "Hello, Ana"
```

http://jsbin.com/xibis/1/edit